# Mongodb c# ElemMatch not working on array

Tags: mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

i am trying to fetch element based on a property of a sub collection.

```
     var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.BusinessRequestStatuses, x => x.RequestId == requestId);
        var res = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

and document structure for "User" looks like this

[image]

BusinessRequestStatuses is array of custom type

```
        public List<BusinessRequestStatus> BusinessRequestStatuses { get; set; }
```

and BusinessRequestStatus is as below

```
public class BusinessRequestStatus
{
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

i am setting up a proper requestId that does exists in sub collection (first) but i dont get any result (res) back.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change `BusinessRequestStatus` into an array ? I suppose that your code builds an expression that is not aware of `_v` in the path. You can check that by enabling MongoDB profiler

Comment: _v is something that comes automatically when i add BusinessRequestStatus. looks like its some mangodb thing.

Comment: i just confirmed that if i remove _t _v and make it just an array it works. but now i have to think how to avoid _t _v 

it is caused by this line

await testRepository.SetCollection<User>(x => x.Id == businessUser.Id, "users", "BusinessRequestStatuses", listOfBusinessRequests.ToArray());

Comment: I've just tried to create simple class with List<MyType> and it's getting stored without any `_t` fields. I suppose that you have some type casting in your code (probably in the code pasted above) and that brings additional field `_t` which represents original type (List)

Comment: @RaasMasood could you add your `Insert` or `Update` method for adding a `BusinessRequestStatus`?